# Pass data from Lightning to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

After getting a list of record in my lightning component from an apex controller, I want to pass the data to a visualforce page for printing the data. Please, I'd like to know how can I send the data from component to the VF page for doing the print.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is use case...? How are you using vf in conjunction with LC...is it iframe inside LC?

Comment: @Ayub I am looking for the best solution possible. I want to display the data on the VF page as a pdf when I click on the search button in my lightning component

Comment: I would suggest ..best solution would be to do not mix lightning and vf...use separate controller for vf...as it will load separately ..so should not be an issue related to performance

Comment: thank you @Ayub for your suggestion. just a question, if I use separate controller for vf, how will I be able to transmit the filtered information?

Comment: @dibocor Can you update how you fixed the issue. I need to pass the data from LC to VF page which has large data. And LC is not added in that specific VF page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some of the basic parameters in the URI for your VF page and then use the parameters to get whatever data you need to display in your PDF.

Eg: URI= /apex/Mypage?id='idvalue'&parameter='parametervalue'

Comment: I am receiving a bad header 404 error (Too  much data). passing a JSON string which is actually a list of data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need either a custom controller or an extension that the page calls when it loads.

Comment: Thanks @Brooks Johnson for you reply, in case I use a custom controller for my VF page, how will I be able to transmit the filtered informations?

Comment: I have a form in my lightning component that allows filtering the information